# jQuery slideToggle of child UL element

Tags: jquery, html

I've searched a number of similar questions on SO and tried the answers there with no success, I'm trying to slideToggle a UL underneath the clicked H3, here is my jQuery:

```
    $("h3").click(function () {
        $("this").parent().next("ul").slideToggle();
    });
```

Here is the mark-up:

```
            <h3 class="accordion-header">Element Type<img class="accordion-marker" src="images/accordion-down.png" /></h3>
        <ul class="accordion">
            <li><input type="checkbox" /><label>ACME Packet 9200</label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" /><label>Audio Code</label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" /><label>CS2K</label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" /><label>IMSS Access</label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" /><label>IMSS Core</label></li>
        </ul>
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("h3").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings("ul").slideToggle();
});
```

Close :) You are looking at the sibling of the H3, not a child element. Also, when using $(this) as it is an object/reference it doesn't require quote marks.

If you are using multiple instances on the page, use this code

```
$("h3").click(function () {
    $(this).next("ul").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your answer, this has toggled the UL (thank you!) the problem I have is that there are several H3's & UL's on the page and it toggles them all, is there a way to identify and just toggle the one below the clicked H3?

Comment: give me 2 minutes. ill take a look for you

Comment: Oh I changed it to $(this).next("ul").slideToggle(); and that worked, you got me in the right direction so I will accept your answer as soon as I can, thanks again.

Comment: Yeah i just checked that too! haha. Not a problem at all :) I shall update my answer for other users however